# Build URL dynamically but strip out port number or ensure HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, url, replace, port

my Link function that uses BuildAbsolute to create URL is not working when the link in the navbar is clicked from an HTTPS page as the url is including port 443 in the url created. From my research it looks like there are a couple ways of getting rid of the port number,  I am trying to use uri.Host and build the URL manually.

But on the line of code that says - `Uri uri = new Uri(string);`

I get invalid expression term 'string'

Here is my original function in my Link.cs file

```
public static string ToCategory(string departmentId, string categoryId, string page)
    {
        DepartmentDetails d = CatalogAccess.GetDepartmentDetails(departmentId);
        string deptUrlName = PrepareUrlText(d.Name);
        CategoryDetails c = CatalogAccess.GetCategoryDetails(categoryId);
        string catUrlName = PrepareUrlText(c.Name);
        if (page == "1")
            return BuildAbsolute(String.Format("{0}-d{1}/{2}-c{3}", deptUrlName, departmentId, catUrlName, categoryId));
        else
            return BuildAbsolute(String.Format("{0}-d{1}/{2}-c{3}/Page-{4}/", deptUrlName, departmentId, catUrlName, categoryId, page));
}
```

and here is the code in my user control that calls the link function

```
  <ul>
     <asp:Datalist ID="deptList4" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:HyperLink ID="navCatList4" runat="server"
                   NavigateUrl= '<%# Link.ToCategory("4", Eval("CategoryID").ToString()) %>'
                   Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()) %>'>
               </asp:HyperLink><br />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Datalist>
 </ul>
```

I tried replacing my BuildAbsolute with the following but it is not working

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string);
return (String.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}-d{3}/{4}-c{5}", uri.Scheme, uri.Host, deptUrlName, departmentId, catUrlName, categoryId));
```

My goal here is to build the url but to make sure if the link is clicked from an https page that the link will not be built with 443 port or an https because that will cause the page to not load.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Replace function saved the day and adjust my code above to what is below based on the suggestion solved my problem.

```
return BuildAbsolute(String.Format("{0}-d{1}/{2}-c{3}", deptUrlName, departmentId, 
    catUrlName, categoryId)).Replace(":443", "").Replace("https://", "http://");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a URL string that might contain some unwanted portions, then you could just do something like this:

```
var sanitizedUrl = urlString.Replace(":443","").Replace("https://","http://");
```

Comment: This worked for me and I just appended and used your code starting with .Replace to my BuildAbsolute line.  thanks.

Comment: This will only work if both https and http are using the standard ports. Which may not always be the case.

Comment: Agreed, this is not the most robust solution.  However,  the question specifically stated 'https' and '443', so this seemed the simplest way to achieve what they wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function BuildAbsolute(string) to render the absolute URL. It is likely that this function is taking the URL port and protocol from the page being requested and using that information to build your URL.

On pages that are https or have a port in the path this will be added to the new path being returned.

You need to change you need to use a new function that strips out the protocol and port from the base URL for the request and then creates your URL.

Comment: this explains my questions very clearly but does not provide any specifics on how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps that's true but you haven't supplied BuildAbsolute and I was suggesting that is where the problem is. Not in the code you posted.